# How to listen to a state and set a timer of how long it would wait for the state to change in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loading skeleton indicator when I'm loading data. What I want to do is to take into consideration users with slow internet connection. So I decided to have a skeleton loading indicator which lasts until the fetching completes. However, I want to show a toast maybe 5 seconds after the loading starts, to indicate to the user that he/she has a slow internet connection. So far I have something like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        // Show toast here
    }, 5000);

    if (!loading) clearTimeout(timer);

}, [loading])
```

But this doesn't seem to work because even after `loading` is set to false, the toast still appear. What am I missing here or is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is the value of `timer` will be different each time the useEffect runs so the clearTimeout won't stop the previous timeout.  Consider doing the clearTimeout in a cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          // Show toast here
      }, 5000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer); 
    }
}, [loading])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the timeout ID returned by `setTimeout` and then use `clearTimeout` in the cleanup of `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (loading) {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            // Show toast here
        }, 5000);
    }

    return () => {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    };
}, [loading]);
```